# Is it good practice to use break and continue in PHP?

Tags: php

Is it a good practice to use `break` and `continue` as sentinel for loops in PHP?

e.g.

```
if (!empty($var))
    break;
```

Comment: Yes, it is. These statements exist for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

```
do {
 if (condition1)
   break;
 some code;
 some code;
 if (condition2)
   break;
 some code;
 some code;
 if (condition3)
   break;
 some code;
 some code;
} while (false);
```

vs.

```
if (!condition1) {
   some code; 
   some code;
   if (!condition2) {
      some code;
      some code;
      if (!condition3) {
         some code;
         some code;
      }
}
```

Some  find the first version an abhomination and difficult to read and love the second version. Some find the first version cleaner and easier to read. As the number of conditions multiply, I tend to find the first version easier to follow, as the second one tends to get more and more difficult to follow the level of nesting. Also if the `if (condition) break;` gets into something only slightly more complex like `if (condition) {some code; break}`, the `do {if .. break; if .. break..;} while(false)` pattern gets even more clear compared with equivalend nested ifs.

Answer (score 2):

In light usage it is ok, but in heavy usage it makes your code spaghetti. `break` and `continue` is basically just a restricted `goto` and as such, use sparingly.

Comment: Except for the fact that with goto you never know if it's jumping backward or forward. With break and continue you know where it jumps

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely is, they're both valid programming constructs.

What is not a good idea is the newly introduced [**GOTO**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php). (Please tell me this was an April fool's joke I didn't see the note about!)

Comment: When the php.net page includes an XKCD comic, you've really got to wonder

Comment: Yeah. I mean, what do you need when a programming language already has an image of unprofessionality? You add *goto*. Sheesh.

Comment: @Erik I am still somehow thinking this was an April fool's joke!

Comment: The inclusion of the XKCD comic on php.net seems to suggest that you shouldn't ever use goto. And I would agree, so why did they include it in 5.3???

Comment: @Jeremy I really have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly correct to use `break` or `continue` as long as it helps to make the code easier to read and understand. I personally use them very rarely, and only when I cannot easily use another structure.

In the case of most `while` statements, it's easier to achieve the same result as a `break` or `continue` by using a boolean variable as the condition for the loop in the first place, and then modifying its value inside the loop.

On the other hand, the best use case for the `break`, in my opinion, is to save resources if you are iterating through an array or something similar with a `for` or `foreach` block and are only interested in processing elements until some item is reached. By using a `break` after reaching this element, it is possible to save on processing power by breaking out of the loop without going over the remaining elements. This makes the code more efficient without making it less legible.

And of course, it is practically impossible to use `switch` statements without `break`.

Another exception is if you need to control nested structures, in which case it is sometimes simpler to use `break n` or `continue n` than manipulate multiple variables concurrently. (Even though this use case is probably the most controversial...)

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer with a couple of questions:

- Why shouldn't it be considered good practice?
- Does it reduce readability of your code?
- Does it slow down your for cycles?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, we use infinite loop and break to improve readability. So yes, you can use it, provided you do it correctly, and for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

For a discussion of break and continue in PHP (and looping in general) have a look at [Advanced loops](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/php/660-advanced-loops.html) - you get the impression that the author can just about manage to swallow break and continue but not break n and continue n.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In 5+ years programming PHP I never had to use break outside of switch statements.

Continue is sometimes used to skip first or last items in iterations, but I don't like it very much.

Why did they reintroduce GOTO ? that's a shame

To answer the question, in

```
if (!empty($var))
    break;
```

Why not use return (if in a method context)

```
if (!empty($var))
    return false;
```

I think this way much clear and makes the caller aware of what's happened inside. A better use for argument errors is using Excecptions, which in facte will break execution a the point they are raised.